# Restangular Multiple IDs in GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm looking at switching from resource to restangular in my AngularJS app. I like the new model, but I have one problem. I can't figure out how to make this API call:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/entity/groups/1,2,3,4/events
```

I have code like this:

```
var GroupService = ['Restangular', function (Restangular) {
    var restAngular = Restangular.withConfig(function (Configurer) {
        Configurer.setBaseUrl('/api/entity');
    });

    return {
        getEvents: function (groupIds) {
            return restAngular.all('groups', groupsIds).getList('events');
        }
    }
}];
```

Is there a way to ask for a set of groups (more than one and not all of them) and then get all events for any of those groups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `several` method of Restangular

```
Restangular.several('accounts', 1234, 123, 12345).customGETLIST('events');
```

P.S.: I think this might be a bug of Restangular that `.getList('events')` is not working.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that in the API. Thank you!

Comment: Can you pass an array as the second argument to several? My backend returns the ids of the objects associations.

Comment: If it just appends the comma separated list, I guess I can just join the array and add it to the end of the base route.

Comment: @CleoR I don't think you can. But you can creatively use apply method.

Comment: @Daiwei wouldn't it be awesome if you could just send an array of ids?

Comment: @Thomas this has been a long time. Maybe their api changed already ;)

Comment: @Daiwei API is still the same, and it's a shame that `several` does not take an array